# RequestLenghtRestriction error on HttpGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application in MVC4 / ASP.NET. Basically what is happening is in my foreach loop, I'm building a list of strings. When that list gets so long and I try to call HttpGet to retrieve that list I get the RequestLengthRestriction error. How can I fix this? Could I just send through javascript instead? If so, how? I'm not sure if I even provided enough information, if not, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: code sample please...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to POST that data.